# How to enable encryption in Rocket Chat?

Tags: meteor, encryption, rocket.chat

I am trying to add an encryption plugin to Rocket chat  - `rocketchat-sharedsecret`. But it requires `jparker:crypto-aes.` and in RocketChat I see only

```
 jparker_crypto-core.js   
 jparker_crypto-core.js.map 
 jparker_crypto-md5.js                                     
 jparker_crypto-md5.js.map
```

How do I add package `jparker:crypto-aes`  and add plugin `rocketchat-sharedsecret`?

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Rocket.Chat; Did you run `meteor add rocketchat:sharedsecret?` What was the output?  You can also join https://demo.rocket.chat and go to #support channel, where we can provide you with all the information you need.

Comment: Here's a relevant thread: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/36